# appending query string with Sitecore URL Rewrite module

Tags: url-rewriting, query-string, sitecore9

I am trying to rewrite incoming URL requests with the Sitecore URL Rewrite module in Sitecore 9. The request come in with the format of www.site.com/find-location/locations/1111 but the current service requires the format to be www.site.com/find-location/locations/?id=1111. I have tried applying the query string of "id=1111" to the Sitecore link and selecting Append query string in the redirect item but the query string is never applied. The inbound rule works correctly as I can set it to point to a specific page without a query string and it will redirect to that page but will not apply a query string. Is there something that I am missing or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by setting the redirect link as an external link and giving it the query string ?id={R:1} which is the matched pattern.